# How to fix "zsh compinit: insecure directories"?

Tags: 16.04, zsh, fakeroot

When I run `fakeroot` in `zsh` it always gives me this warning:

```
zsh compinit: insecure directories, run compaudit for list.
Ignore insecure directories and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]?
```

I can continue by pressing <kbd>y</kbd> and then `fakeroot` works.

I'm wondering what this error message is and how to fix it.

(If I press <kbd>n</kbd> `fakeroot` still continues (verified with `whoami`), which seems odd to me.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This made the error go away:

```
cd /usr/local/share/zsh
sudo chmod -R 755 ./site-functions
sudo chown -R root:root ./site-functions
```

I'm still unsure what the error meant or why it happened, though.

Credit: [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762280/zsh-compinit-insecure-directories) which in turn got the solution from [a post on the zsh mailing list](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2008/msg00566.html)

Comment: An explanation to why the error happens was added some time later in that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762280/zsh-compinit-insecure-directories#answer-43544733

Answer (score 2):

I simply followed what was written there.

```
zsh compinit: insecure directories, run compaudit for list.
Ignore insecure directories and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]?
```

I ignored these. After that, I ran `compaudit`,

```
# compaudit
```

It showed me 2 directories,

```
/usr/local/share/zsh/
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/
```

So, insecure means something is wrong with their permissions, I changed the permissions to secure them and the error went away.

I also checked that both directories were empty, so I deleted both of them, which I would not recommend, but still I did.

Answer (score 1):

To Fix Error

> zsh compinit: insecure files, run compaudit for list.
>   Ignore insecure files and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]?

I ran 2 commands:

command 1.

```bsh
compaudit
```

output:

```
There are insecure files:
/usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions/_code
```

Then I ran:

command 2.

```bsh
sudo chown root /usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions/_code
```

cheers

Comment: This worked, but now the terminal take some time (after open) until be ready to type.

Answer (score 0):

This morning, some packages in my system updated, and left me with this error message.

Apparently, something in the update changed the username and group to numbers, instead of `root`, as so:

```sh
# There are insecure files: /usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions/_code
# sudo ls -alh
-rw-r--r-- 1  131  142 2.6K 2019-10-10 16:28 _code
```

I simply changed the user and group for this file back to `root` and the problem went away. I did *not* need to change any permissions, and would caution against doing so unless the underlying cause of the problem is understood.

`sudo chown root _code && sudo chgrp root _code`

After switching `131` and `142` back to `root`, this error message from zsh went away.